# Find the limit $\lim_{ n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left\lfloor\frac{3n}{10}\right\rfloor}{n}$

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ denotes greatest integer function then
$n \ge 1$  and is a positive integer

$$\lim_{ n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left\lfloor\frac{3n}{10}\right\rfloor}{n}$$

Comment: What do you mean by "N"? is it typo mistake?

Comment: To clarify:  $N=n$? Hint:  a good way to get a feel for problems like this is to simply try large values.  It is easy, for example to evaluate your expression whenever $n$ is an integer. What if $n=100.35$? or $10000.7$?

Comment: @Chiranjeev I think that you don't have the rights to change $N$ to $n$ because this changes the meaning of the question

Comment: yeah that's why i asked to OP @ Elaqqad Sorry for that

Comment: OTOH  the question is unanswerable in its original form, and it's highly probable that the OP meant to write $n$ instead of $N$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formula $\displaystyle (x-1)\leq \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x\;,$ Where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is an floor function of $x$

So  Put $\displaystyle x = \frac{3n}{10}\;,$ we get

$\displaystyle\frac{3n}{10}-1\leq \lfloor \frac{3n}{10}\rfloor \leq \frac{3n}{10}$

So $\displaystyle  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{3n}{10}-1}{n}< \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\lfloor \frac{3n}{10}\rfloor}{n} \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{3n}{10}}{n}$

So we get $\displaystyle \frac{3}{10}<\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\lfloor \frac{3n}{10}\rfloor}{n}\leq \frac{3}{10}$

So Using Sandwitch Theorem, We get  Limit $\displaystyle = \frac{3}{10}$

Comment: Wait, something is wrong (maybe it's only notation). But $x<y\leq x$ is tautologically false. When you do the inequalities, you do it without he limits. When you apply limits, then you may get equality on the boundaries, so your $<$ should be a $\leq$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$, you get
$$
\frac{\frac{3n}{10}-1}{n} < \frac{\left\lfloor\frac{3n}{10}\right\rfloor}{n} \le \frac{3}{10}.
$$
Conclude.

Comment: please ^give your answer as the largest integer after multiplying by 10^6

Comment: This is not what you asked in the OP..?